# In C#, perform "static" copy into a substring of a StringBuilder object

Tags: c#

To build a sparsely populated fixed width record, I would like to copy a string field into a StringBuilder object, starting at a given position.  A nice syntax for this would have been

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(' ', 100);
string fieldValue = "12345";
int startPos = 16; 
int endPos = startPos + fieldValue.Length - 1;
sb[startPos..endPos] = fieldValue; // no such syntax
```

I could obviously do this C style, one character at a time:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii++; ii < fieldValue.Length)
    sb[startPos + ii] = fieldValue[ii];
```

But this seems way too cumbersome for c#, plus it uses a loop where the resulting machine code could more efficiently use a bulk copy, which can make a difference if the strings involved were long.  Any ideas for a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own specialized string builder class that uses the efficient machinery of `char[]` and `string` underneath the hood, in particular [`String.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copyto.aspx):

```
public class FixedStringBuilder
{
    char[] buffer;

    public FixedStringBuilder(int length)
    {
        buffer = new string(' ', length).ToCharArray();
    }

    public FixedStringBuilder Replace(int index, string value)
    {
        value.CopyTo(0, buffer, index, value.Length);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new string(buffer);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FixedStringBuilder sb = new FixedStringBuilder(100);
        string fieldValue = "12345";
        int startPos = 16; 
        sb.Replace(startPos, fieldValue);
        string buffer = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly I was looking for.  Would never occur to me to look for it as a method of the immutable System.String :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your original algorithm can be supported in the following way

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(new string(' ', 100));
string toInsert = "HELLO WORLD";
int atIndex = 10;
builder.Remove(atIndex, toInsert.Length);
builder.Insert(atIndex, toInsert);

Debug.Assert(builder.Length == 100);
Debug.Assert(builder.ToString().IndexOf(toInsert) == 10);
```

Comment: It could be even slower than char-by-char replacing because of shifting tail back and forth. I'd not recommend that instead of a simple loop.

Comment: For a single algorithmic operation such as this, I'd just use a string and forget the builder altogether, it's overkill. For something I would perform multiple times, say, in a loop, I'd want efficiency, certainly, but also something easy to reason about. `char` replacement operations in an array would rank lower on the reasonability meter, so the presumed performance gain would need to be worth it.

Comment: It depends on the scenario heavily. If you read big file for example and replacing there several places in the beginning - this would be great loss of performance. And for readability `for` and `Remote`/`Insert` variants are almost equal here imo. So it is up to OP basically :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to your goal is to convert the source string in a char array, then substitute the cells. Any char array can be converted back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

why are you pre-allocating memory in the string builder (it is only support performance).

i would append the known prefix, then the actual value and then the postfix to the string.

something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(prefix).Append(value).Append(postfix);
```

Comment: This does not address the "seek" scenario, where you have a static character sequence of a known fixed length, and you want to overwrite an small area of it at a given "address".